# search-form-inputs tag not working properly with econditions

Tags: moqui

i'm doing an entity-find with econditions and I put the result list in a form-list element on my page. I want the ability of sorting on columns so i've put a `<search-form-inputs/>` tag at the end of my entity-find.
the problem is that the entity-find doesn't work properly for the econditions I've included (Its results are not what they are supposed to be!)

and when I remove the `<search-form-inputs/>` tag everything just works fine.
any suggestions? maybe I'm not using this tag in the right way.

```
                   <entity-find entity-name="me.myJointView" list="itmTemp" distinct="true">
                    <econdition field-name="myId" operator="less-equals" from="rNTo" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econdition field-name="myId" operator="greater-equals" from="rNFrom" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econdition field-name="myName" from="fName" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econdition field-name="mySurname" from="lName" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econdition field-name="myDate" operator="less-equals" from="aDTo" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econdition field-name="someId" operator="equals" from="so" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econdition field-name="someOtherId" operator="equals" from="rm" ignore-if-empty="true"/>
                    <econditions combine="or">
                        <econdition field-name="myStateEnumId" operator="equals" value="something"/>
                        <econdition field-name="myStateEnumId" operator="equals" value="somethingElse"/>
                    </econditions>
                    <econditions combine="or">
                        <econditions combine="and">
                            <econdition field-name="aDate" from="null"/>
                            <econdition field-name="myDate" operator="greater-equals" to-field-name="aDate"/>
                        </econditions>
                        <econditions combine="and">
                            <econdition field-name="myDate" operator="less-equals" to-field-name="dDate"/>
                            <econdition field-name="myDate" operator="greater-equals" to-field-name="aDate"/>
                        </econditions>
                    </econditions>
                    <search-form-inputs/>
                    <select-field field-name="myId"/>
                    <select-field field-name="myName"/>
                    <select-field field-name="mySurname"/>
                    <select-field field-name="MyDate"/>
                    <order-by field-name="myDate,RECETEST.lastUpdatedStamp"/>
                </entity-find>
```

Comment: Could you explain more of what you mean by 'Its results are not what they are supposed to be'? What were the expected results and how were they different from the actual results? This is a complex query, all sorts of stuff going on and many things that will behave differently depending on parameters passed. It may also be helpful to look at the actual SQL generated for each find which you can do with the Tools => Query Stats screen or using the EntityFind.getQueryTextList() method (search around the code for examples, there are various in OOTB screens and services).

Comment: I mean that the results of the entity-finds are different when I remove the search-form-inputs tag. some records don't show up when I add the tag. solved the problem somehow but facing another issue that I've explaind below. @DavidE.Jones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a form-list in my screen that its column names was identical to the fields I set econditions on. something like:

```
<form-list  name="list" list="receptions"  headre-dialog="true" paginate="true">
```

```
                    <field name="mySurname" skip-form="false">
                        <header-field show-order-by="true"><text-find hide-options="true"/></header-field>
                        <default-field><display/></default-field>
                    </field>
                    <field name="myDate" skip-form="false">
                        <header-field show-order-by="true"><text-find hide-options="true"/></header-field>
                        <default-field><display/></default-field>
                    </field>
                    <field name="editButton">
                        <default-field>
                            <link url="edit" parameter-map="[myId:myId]" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" btn-type="info" />
                        </default-field>
                    </field>
                    <form-list-column>
                        <field-ref name="myId" skip-form="true"/>
                    </form-list-column>
                    <form-list-column>
                        <field-ref name="myName"/>
                    </form-list-column>
                    <form-list-column>
                        <field-ref name="mySurname"/>
                    </form-list-column>
                    <form-list-column>
                        <field-ref name="myDate"/>
                    </form-list-column>
                    <form-list-column>
                        <field-ref name="editButton"/>
                    </form-list-column>
                    <field-layout>
                        <fields-not-referenced/>
                        <field-row>
                            <field-ref name="myId"/>
                            <field-ref name="myName"/>
                            <field-ref name="mySurname"/>
                            <field-ref name="myDate"/>
                            <field-ref name="editButton"/>
                        </field-row>
                    </field-layout>
                </form-list>
```

I added the line below and removed orderBy statement at the end of my entity-find:

```
 <search-form-inputs input-fields-map="[orderByField:ec.web.parameters.orderByField]" default-order-by="myDate,myId,mySurname,myName,myDate" />
```

and checked from the query stats screen that the query produced by the two entity-finds in this topic are the same (apart from the orderBy statement added in the new query) except that:

1- the entity-find in this post add a "limit 20 offset 0" at the end of the query (which i can handle by setting a high limit)

2- I can't orderBy `RECETEST.lastUpdatedStamp` (which I used at the entity-find definition in the main question) anymore. AND I NEED THIS FUNCTIONALITY! WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what is in your context and you will see exactly what is happening to elicit that behaviour. (e.g. you could use the 'label' tag on your screen to return "== ${context} ==" etc.).

And if you only want column sorting then make your own input-fields-map like [orderByField:ec.web.parameters.orderByField], and put your default-order-by in with search-form-inputs too.

```
<search-form-inputs input-fields-map="xxx" default-order-by="xxx" />
```